# Error after configuring aws

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is my error message:

> Excon::Error::Socket in Admin::ProductsController#update
>
> Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
>
> Extracted source (around line #386):

```
  def write_nonblock(s, exception: true)
    flush
    syswrite_nonblock(s, exception: exception)
  end
```

My initializer looks like this...

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',                        
    aws_access_key_id:     'X',                       
    aws_secret_access_key: 'X',                       
    region:                'eu-west-2',                 
    host:                  's3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com'
  config.fog_directory  = 'xxxx'                         
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Did not configure ideally

You can follow like this

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
   config.fog_credentials = {
     :provider              => 'AWS',
     :aws_access_key_id     => 'aws_access_key_id',
     :aws_secret_access_key => 'aws_secret_access_key ',
     :region                => 'eu-west-2'
   } #=> end credentials
   config.fog_directory    = 'bucket-name'
end
```

For more explanation, you can follow [this](http://lifesforlearning.com/uploading-images-with-carrierwave-to-s3-on-rails/)

I think will help